# I have a java blackjack app. How to make it server-client?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, class, client-server

I have a pretty simple blackjack app, but I must to make it client-server and I have no idea how. I would be infinitely grateful for any help.

So, here is main **class Game**:

```
package game;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Deck deck;
    public Player player = new Player("player");
    public Player dealer = new Player("dealer");

    int dealerCount = 0;
    int playerCount = 0;

    private JButton jbtnHit = new JButton("Hit");
    private JButton jbtnStay = new JButton("Stay");
    private JButton jbtnDeal = new JButton("Deal");

    private JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel(" ", JLabel.CENTER);
    private JLabel jlblDealerCount = new JLabel(" ", JLabel.CENTER);
    private JLabel jlblPlayerCount = new JLabel(" ", JLabel.CENTER);

    JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel dealerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel countPanel = new JPanel();

    Game() {
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("BlackJack");
        gameFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("cards/10.png"));
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        buttonsPanel.add(jbtnHit);
        buttonsPanel.add(jbtnStay);
        buttonsPanel.add(jbtnDeal);
        statusPanel.add(jlblStatus);
        countPanel.add(jlblDealerCount);
        countPanel.add(jlblPlayerCount);

        jbtnHit.addActionListener(this);
        jbtnStay.addActionListener(this);
        jbtnDeal.addActionListener(this);

        jbtnHit.setEnabled(false);
        jbtnStay.setEnabled(false);

        dealerPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        playerPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        buttonsPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        statusPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        countPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        gameFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gameFrame.add(dealerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        gameFrame.add(playerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        gameFrame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        gameFrame.add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        gameFrame.add(countPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        gameFrame.repaint();
        gameFrame.setSize(500, 350);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void hitPlayer() {
        Card newCard = player.dealTo(deck.dealFrom());
        playerPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("cards/" + newCard.toString())));
        playerPanel.updateUI();
    }

    private void hitDealerDown() {
        Card newCard = dealer.dealTo(deck.dealFrom());
        dealerPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("cards/b2fv.png")));
        dealerPanel.updateUI();
    }

    private void hitDealer() {
        Card newCard = dealer.dealTo(deck.dealFrom());
        dealerPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("cards/" + newCard.toString())));
        dealerPanel.updateUI();
    }

    private void deal() {
        playerPanel.removeAll();
        dealerPanel.removeAll();
        playerPanel.updateUI();
        dealerPanel.updateUI();
        player.reset();
        dealer.reset();
        if (deck == null || deck.size() < 15) {
            deck = new Deck();
            deck.shuffle();
            jlblStatus.setText("Shuffling");
        }
        hitPlayer();
        hitDealerDown();
        hitPlayer();
        hitDealer();
    }

    private void checkWinner() {
        dealerPanel.removeAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < dealer.inHand(); i++) {
            dealerPanel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("cards/" + dealer.cards[i].toString())));
        }
        if (player.value() > 21) {
            jlblStatus.setText("Player Busts");
            dealerCount++;
        } else if (dealer.value() > 21) {
            jlblStatus.setText("Dealer Busts");
            playerCount++;
        } else if (dealer.value() == player.value()) {
            jlblStatus.setText("Push");
        } else if (dealer.value() < player.value()) {
            jlblStatus.setText("Player Wins");
            playerCount++;
        } else {
            jlblStatus.setText("Dealer Wins");
            dealerCount++;
        }
        jlblDealerCount.setText(dealerCount+" :");
        jlblPlayerCount.setText(""+playerCount);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == jbtnHit) {
            hitPlayer();
            if (player.value() > 21) {
                checkWinner();
                jbtnHit.setEnabled(false);
                jbtnStay.setEnabled(false);
                jbtnDeal.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource() == jbtnStay) {
            while (dealer.value() < 17 || player.value() > dealer.value()) {
                hitDealer();
            }
            checkWinner();
            jbtnHit.setEnabled(false);
            jbtnStay.setEnabled(false);
            jbtnDeal.setEnabled(true);
        }

        if (e.getSource() == jbtnDeal) {
            deal();
            jlblStatus.setText(" ");
            jbtnHit.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnStay.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnDeal.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

Here is **class Card**:

```
package game;

 class Card {

    private int cardNumber;
    private int rank;
    private String front;

    Card(int cardNumber, int rank, String front) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.front = front;
    }

    public boolean isAce() {
        return rank == 0;
    }

    public int rank() {
        if (rank == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (rank >= 9) {
            return 10;
        }
        return rank + 1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.front;
    }
}
```

Here is **class Deck**:

```
package game;

public class Deck {

    final static int DECK_SIZE = 52;
    private Card[] cards;
    private int N = 0;

    public Deck() {
        cards = new Card[DECK_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                cards[N] = new Card(N, j, i + "" + j + ".png");
                N++;
            }
        }
    }

    public Card dealFrom() {
        return cards[--N];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (N == 0);
    }

    public int size() {
        return N;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int r = (int) (Math.random() * i);
            Card swap = cards[i];
            cards[i] = cards[r];
            cards[r] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is **class Player**:

```
package game;

public class Player {

    final static int MAX_CARDS = 52;
    public Card[] cards = new Card[MAX_CARDS];
    private int N = 0;
    private String name;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int inHand() {
        return N;
    }

    public Card dealTo(Card c) {
        cards[N++] = c;
        return c;
    }

    public void reset() {
        N = 0;
    }

    public int value() {
        int val = 0;
        boolean hasAce = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            val = val + cards[i].rank();
            if (cards[i].isAce()) {
                hasAce = true;
            }
        }
        if (hasAce && (val <= 11)) {
            val = val + 10;
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

I need any information and samples of how I should do this game client-server and multithreaded.
**This should be network application with using of sockets.**

Answer (score 1):

When you're writing a networked app, you have to first decide what data is shared between by users of the game. For Blackjack, the data to share (AKA the "game state") is pretty simple:

1. Player whose turn it is
2. Cards that are still in the deck
3. Cards that are on the table for each player
4. How much money each player has

Once you have all this planned out, you can create objects to represent the game state. For example:

```
public class GameState {
    public enum Suit { HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES }
    public enum Rank { ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX ... ACE }
    public static class Card {
       Suit suit;
       Rank rank;
    }
    public static class Deck {
       List<Card> cards; // Cards remaining in the deck
    }
    public static class Player {
       // Cards on the table for a player
       List<Card> cards;
       Integer id;
       Double money;
    }
    HashMap<Integer, Player> players;
    Integer activePlayerId;
}
```

Next, we need a mechanism to sync this state between all the players. One way to do this for a game like Blackjack is to sync the whole state after each player's turn. That is, at the end of each turn, send the whole game state over the network to all the players. To send game state, it's easiest to have a central server process that keeps a copy of the most recent state. The central server sends the game state to the players periodically, to keep them in sync.

Now, we need a protocol that the clients can use to communicate with the server. At the beginning of the game, clients connect, then wait for the server to start the game. After that, the clients and server communicate in lockstep, almost as if they're having a conversation. Here's an example:

```
Client 1: Connect 
Server: OK 
Client 2: Connect 
Server: OK 
Server: Start game 
Server: Sync <send the initial game state> 
Server: Place bids
Client 1: Bid 50
Client 2: Bid 100
Server: Client 1's turn
Client 1: Stay
Server: Sync <send new game state>
Server: Client 2's turn
Client 2: Hit 
Server: Sync <send new game state> 
...
```

etc. until the game ends. To send the data and protocol dialogue between clients and the server, you can use sockets. I won't cover that here, since there are plenty of tutorials on using sockets out there on the Interwebs, [like this one.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Good luck, and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the implementation into at least three layers : ui layer, service layer, and data layer. The client handles the ui layer, and service requests, the server answers requests, and communicates with the db.

You can host the server in a container or in a cloud, like GAE.

The client will normally communicate via HTTP, by either get or post.

Comment: Hi, what is "GAE" and is it still a relevant solution these days?  If so, can you provide a source reference to learn more about GAE?